# Updating deeply nested struct

Tags: elixir

So let's say I have the following structure:

```
%Car{details: [%CarDetail{prices: [%Price{euro: 5}]}]}
```

and I want to add another price struct to the prices list of the car detail, how would I do that?

Obviously the real example is way deeper so I cannot use pattern matching and I can't come up with a way to use `put_in/3` or something of the kind.

Some help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please show the desired result. Would it be `%Car{details: [%CarDetail{prices: [%Price{euro: 5}], %Price{euro: 10}]}]}`?

Comment: @mudasobwa Yep, that's it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `Kernel.update_in/3` to traverse nested structures. It will not work by simply passing a list of keys to `update_in`, because neither structs nor lists implement the access protocol. This is where `Access.key!/1` and `Access.all` come in. Be aware though, that the following piece of code will add the price to *all* car details, should there be more than one. If you need to update specific details only, you can either use `Access.at/1` or [implement your own access function](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#get_and_update_in/3-examples).

```
update_in car, [Access.key!(:details), Access.all, Access.key!(:prices)], fn(prices) ->
  [%Price{euro: 12345} | prices]
end
```

Comment: Neat! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: link is broken. What did you mean by  *implement your own access function*?

Comment: @tungli link fixed, please refer to that for examples.

Comment: Actually, `Access.filter` might come in handy when you need to update only specific entries. See examples in docs: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#filter/1-examples

Answer (score 1):

The macro `put_in/2` makes this easy:

```
def add_price(%Car{details: %CarDetails{prices: prices}} = car, new_price) do
  put_in(car.details.prices, [%Price{euro: new_price} | prices])
end
```

Comment: This won't work, the pattern matching doesn't match the data structure in the example. But you would also need to use `Access` since structs and maps have different access rules.